# Dynamic casting in C/Cython

Tags: c, casting, cython

Let we say that we have at about 100 different struct types, and we also have some function which returns void pointer to one of 100 mentioned struct types.

So, we also have string representation of type, eg. if we have defined 
`typedef struct SomeStr {...};`, for that struct we have string `char *strName = "SomeStr";`

So, is there any way to do 'dynamic' casting on the runtime to appropriate type, if we have void pointer and string containing the name of type, or we will need to do one by one cast?

Answer (score 0):

No, C has no such functionality (called [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29)). You have to use e.g. a chain of string comparisons and cast one by one.